# CSS code to modify style attribute of a th

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I need to create the CSS that will modify the style of:

```
<th class="sort-column" data-is-only-head="false" data-field="daysElapsedfromInfoReceived" style="text-align: left;"><!-- react-text: 463 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 464 -->Days Elapsed From Info. Received<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 465 -->  <!-- /react-text --><span class="order"><span class="dropdown"><span class="caret" style="margin: 10px 0px 10px 5px; color: rgb(204, 204, 204);"></span></span><span class="dropup"><span class="caret" style="margin: 10px 0px; color: rgb(204, 204, 204);"></span></span></span><div></div></th>
```

(Got this from chrome)

so style = "text-align: left; white-space: normal"

I tried:

```
th .sort-column {
    text-align: left;
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

and also:

```
th.sort-column {
    text-align: left;
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

with no luck. I need the content of this th to be in multiple lines.

According to Chrome, the next is the CSS hierarchy:

[image]

Comment: Remove the space/gap between `th .sort-column ` to `th.sort-column`

Comment: tried that, too... no luck. Could this be because of boot strap

Comment: Yes, Bootstrap's CSS might be more specific and overriding yours. Post a [mcve] please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've formatted your table a little bit and colored it grey to show the cell size:

```css
th.sort-column {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: grey;
  min-width: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table>
  <th class="sort-column">Days Elapsed From</th>
  <th class="sort-column">Info</th>
  <th class="sort-column">Received</th>
</table>
```

> I need the content of this th to be in multiple lines.

When changing `min-width` into `width` that'll force the browser to introduce linebreaks:

```css
th.sort-column {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 6rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table>
  <th class="sort-column">Days Elapsed From</th>
  <th class="sort-column">Info</th>
  <th class="sort-column">Received</th>
</table>
```

Comment: While this is not the direct answer, thanks to your suggestion I went to try another alternative and found I was compiling on the wrong folder! I mean, wrong copy of my project :-(  Thx

Comment: Oh, I missed out on Bootstrap, sorry. Added it and luckily the formatting stays unchanged. You might be targeted by Bootstrap's CSS through if you have an actual table with all the parts it's made of.